# Is there a way to provide multiple masks to BERT in MLM task?

Tags: natural-language-processing, bert, language-model

I'm facing a situation where I've to fetch probabilities from BERT MLM for multiple words in a single sentence.

```
Original : "Mountain Dew is an energetic drink"
Masked : "[MASK] is an energetic drink"
```

But BERT MLM task doesn't consider two tokens at a time for the MASK. I strongly think that there should be some sort of work around that I'm unable to find other than fine-tuning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer in the original [BERT git repo](https://github.com/google-research/bert)

> ***** New May 31st, 2019: Whole Word Masking Models *****
>
> This is a release of several new models which were the result of an
> improvement the pre-processing code.
>
> In the original pre-processing code, we randomly select WordPiece
> tokens to mask. For example:

```
Input Text: 
the man jumped up , put his basket on phil ##am ##mon ' s
head Original Masked Input: [MASK] man [MASK] up , put his [MASK] on
phil [MASK] ##mon ' s head
```

> The new technique is called Whole Word Masking. In this case, we
> always mask all of the the tokens corresponding to a word at once. The
> overall masking rate remains the same.

```
Whole Word Masked Input: 
the man [MASK] up , put his basket on [MASK] [MASK] [MASK] ' s head
```

> The training is identical -- we still predict each masked WordPiece
> token independently. The improvement comes from the fact that the
> original prediction task was too 'easy' for words that had been split
> into multiple WordPieces.
>
> This can be enabled during data generation by passing the flag

```
--do_whole_word_mask=True
```

> to create_pretraining_data.py.